# How should default values from a WebAPI be handled in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly project and a WebAPI project. One of my WebAPI controllers returns a default value when the requested object cannot be found. The HttpClient sees an HTTP 204 No Content response, but HttpClient doesn't know how to handle that and throws a `NotSupportedException`.

As a quick and dirty hack, I have been doing something similar to this:

```
MyObject retrievedObject = default;

try 
{
    retrievedObject = HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<MyObject>("/api/MyObjects/<NonExistentObjectId>");
}
catch (NotSupportedException e)
{
    // do nothing
}

if (retrievedObject != default) {
    // do something with retrievedObject   
}
```

A couple of questions:

Is there a better way to handle this on the Blazor WebAssembly side?

Is it a bad idea to have the WebAPI return a default value (HTTP 204) when the object cannot be found?